# git: checkout all files from a branch (but stay at current branch)

Tags: git

I can checkout a particular file from a branch into current branch with `git checkout branchname filename`. How can I checkout **all the files** in `branchname` into current branch?

`git checkout branchname` does not fit my need since that will switch me away from current branch.

`git merge branchname` does not fit my need since I do not want to create a commit yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
git reset --hard branchname
```

Note that this *will* get rid of any changes you had in the current branch that aren't in the other branch, and any uncommitted changes you might have had laying around. It will keep you on your current branch but change it to point at the commit which `branchname` refers to.

If you instead want to not change what commit is being pointed at, you could instead just check out the whole tree:

```
cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
git checkout branchname .
```

This is the equivalent of running `git checkout branchname filename` for the entire repository.

Comment: Another way to not change the pointed-to commit is to put it back afterwards: after the `git reset --hard $branchname` (or even `git checkout $branchname`), `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}`; or to skip the two-step entirely just use the lowlevel `git read-tree -um HEAD $branchname`.

Comment: Note that if you want to make your state match the target branch but not change the history of your current branch (which is what I was trying to do), you additionally need to worry about files *deleted* in the target branch once you've done the `git checkout branchname .` step. I solved this by following it up with `git diff branchname --name-only | xargs git rm`.

Answer (score 3):

**The simplest solution to checkout all chenged files from another branch in uncommited state is:**

```
git checkout branchname .
```